# When I run sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none it gives me error

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When I run `sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none` it gives me this error and I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4.

```
Error starting cluster: cmd failed: sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.16.2:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap

: running command: sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.16.2:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap
 output: [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.16.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [WARNING FileExisting-ebtables]: ebtables not found in system path
    [WARNING FileExisting-socat]: socat not found in system path
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of validated versions: 19.03.4. Latest validated version: 18.09
    [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "minikube" could not be reached
    [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "minikube": lookup minikube on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
    [WARNING Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Port-10251]: Port 10251 is in use
    [ERROR Port-10252]: Port 10252 is in use
    [ERROR Port-2380]: Port 2380 is in use
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
: running command: sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.16.2:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap
.: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `none` driver makes a lot of assumptions that would normally be handled by the VM setup process used by all other drivers. In this case you can see that some of the ports it expects to use are already in use so it won't continue. You would need to remove whatever is using those ports. The `none` driver is generally used for very niche situations, almost always in an ephemeral CI environment, though maybe also check out KinD as a newer tool that might address that use case better. If you just want to run a local dev environment on Linux without an intermediary VM, maybe try k3s or microk8s instead.

Comment: thanks for your support but could you please tell me that whenever i am trying to run kubectl it shows The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port? what's the reason behind this ? i will create a new question on this if you say.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/)  there is a note about the need of having these ports free. You need to sort it out what is using them to get rid of these errors:

```
[WARNING Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
[ERROR Port-10251]: Port 10251 is in use
[ERROR Port-10252]: Port 10252 is in use
[ERROR Port-2380]: Port 2380 is in use
```

This is preventing you system to load and it's described on the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/). To investigate you can use the following command:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :10251
```

If you don't have this command installed you can install it using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lsof
```

Running minikube with `--vm-driver=none` is possible but not recommended. By using none Driver, you have decreased reliability, decreased security, risk of data loss and more. Refer to [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/) for more details.

There is an issue opened to address these security problems.

[Full list of open ‘none’ driver issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/labels/co%2Fnone-driver)

The best way of doing it on Linux is using kvm. To accomplish that you can follow these instructions (assuming you have [Docker CE installed](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)):

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system
$ sudo adduser $USER libvirt
```

And run minikube with kvm2 driver:

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver kvm2 --kubernetes-version v1.15.0
```